# How to get count of certain text in DataTable rows using C#?

Tags: c#, datatable

I have a DataTable

```
Id readTime                DeviceId Sensor1 Sensor2 Sensor3 ........  Sensor13
1  2015-01-26 09:50:27.000  123      T       T      F                  F
.
.
. 
13  2015-01-26 09:50:27.000  874      T       F      F                 T
```

I want add two columns to this DataTable for get count of 'T' and 'F' value in every row of datatable.

```
Id readTime                DeviceId Sensor1 Sensor2 Sensor3 ........  Sensor13 CountT CountF
1  2015-01-26 09:50:27.000  123      T       T      F                  F         6      7
.
.
. 
13  2015-01-26 09:50:27.000  874      T       F      F                 T         8      5
```

How can I do this ?

My Query

```
 string sql=Select * from SensorTable 


public DataTable ()
{
 DataTable tb=someClass.DataTableMethod(sql);
 return tb;
}
```

Comment: What's the definition of `someClass`? What's does it's `DataTableMethod()` consist of?

Comment: Bad DB design. Remove columns from device table, create table Sensors and make relation to device table - you'll be able to achieve your current goal much easier.

Comment: Why not loop over all rows in the data table, then loop over all sensors in a row?

Comment: @TZHX return a DataTable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone an empty table with the same columns and add two for the sum:

```
DataTable tblResult = tb.Clone();
tblResult.Columns.Add("CountT", typeof(int));
tblResult.Columns.Add("CountF", typeof(int));
```

Select columns which are used to calculate the T- and F-Values with LINQ:

```
DataColumn[] sensorColumns = tb.Columns.Cast<DataColumn>()
    .Where(col => col.ColumnName.StartsWith("Sensor"))
    .ToArray();
```

Use a loop to add the rows to the second table including the sum-columns:

```
foreach (DataRow row in tb.Rows)
{
    tblResult.ImportRow(row);
    DataRow newRow = tblResult.Rows[tblResult.Rows.Count - 1];
    newRow["CountT"] = sensorColumns.Count(c => row.Field<string>(c) == "T");
    newRow["CountF"] = sensorColumns.Count(c => row.Field<string>(c) == "F");
}
```

You need to add `using System.Linq` to be able to use the LINQ extension methods.

Comment: Thank you so much Sir.Excellent solution for me.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach is to use the [Expression](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datacolumn.expression(v=vs.110).aspx) property of the DataColumn.

Define two expressions that counts the fields of your table with the 'T' char and 'F' char in the Sensors columns
(or whatever you use for true value and false)

```
    string expT = "IIF(Sensor1='T',1,0) + IIF(Sensor2='T',1,0) + IIF(Sensor3='T',1,0)";
    string expF = "IIF(Sensor1='F',1,0) + IIF(Sensor2='F',1,0) + IIF(Sensor3='F',1,0)";
    ....
```

Now add the two counter columns to your table with the associated expression

```
    DataTable tb=someClass.DataTableMethod(sql);
    tb.Columns.Add("CountF", typeof(int), expF);
    tb.Columns.Add("CountT", typeof(int), expT);
```